# Restart program tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering on how I can create a restart button that once clicked, can restart the entire script. What I thought was that you destroy the window then un-destroy it but apparently there is no un-destroy function.

Comment: Seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/731887/1072229

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting the main GUI window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731887/resetting-the-main-gui-window)

Answer (score 19):

I found a way of doing it for a generic python program on this website: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/260268/restart-your-python-program. I wrote an example with a basic tkinter GUI to test it:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program.
    Note: this function does not return. Any cleanup action (like
    saving data) must be done before calling this function."""
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Hello World!").pack()
Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would Like to Use this Function:-

First of All Import **os** Module

```
import os
```

Then Use this Code:-

```
# Restarts the Whole Window    
def restart():
    root.destroy()
    os.startfile("main.py")
```

Or if You want no console behind then Simply Change the extension of the file to **.pyw**

And Run this Code:-

```
# Restarts the Whole Window    
def restart():
    root.destroy()
    os.startfile("main.pyw")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works as well but is quite harsh, i.e. the entire environment is lost.

```
# kills the whole application and starts a fresh one
def restart():
    root.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    root.mainloop()
```