# Restart button for a tkinter tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tic-tac-toe with Tkinter with a canvas as a school homework and I've ran into a problem: I do not know how to make the restart button (the function to be more precise).

So I've searched how i could make one. But the function given on this post ([Restart program tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655618/restart-program-tkinter)) just gives me this when I start the program:

```
The kernel process exited.
```

I also simply tried to just reset all the values to their default one and erase the canvas but it doesn't work:

```
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

Does anyone know what I have to put to make a restart function ? Thank you.

Comment: Completely restarting your code seems a bit drastic. I think you are on the right way by resetting all the variables and erasing the canvas. Try <code>canvas.delete("all")</code> to clear the canvas.