bad window path name tkinter
I am trying to code rock paper scissors in tkinter python but my reset button command gives me the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__  
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/---------/OneDrive - -------------/python/rock paper scissors.py", line 26, in reset
    run()
  File "c:/Users/-----------/OneDrive - ---------------/python/rock paper scissors.py", line 186, in run
    choose_player_number()
  File "c:/Users/--------------/OneDrive - -----------------/python/rock paper scissors.py", line 181, in choose_player_number
    one_player.grid(column= 2, row=1)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2220, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button5"
PS C:\Users\N.Westrich> 

I don't know how to access the tkinter library, so i don't know what is throwing the program off.
My code is here:
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1400x860")
window.title = "Rock paper scissors"

result = Label(window, text= "result will appear here", bg="green")
player_number = ""
list_of_integers = ["1", "2", "3"]

title = Label(window, text = "Rock paper scissors" , bg= "blue", fg = "white", font= "Times")
title.grid(column=3, row=0)

def reset():
    filler.destroy
    filler2.destroy
    filler3.destroy
    title.destroy
    result.destroy
    rock.destroy
    paper.destroy
    scissors.destroy
    reset1.destroy
    run()

reset1 = Button(window, text = "Reset", command= reset, fg="blue", bg = "yellow")

def evaluate_rock():
    global computer_input
    if computer_input == "3":
        win()
    elif computer_input == "2":
        loose()
    else:
        draw()

def evaluate_scissors():
    global computer_input
    if computer_input == "2":
        win()
    elif computer_input == "1":
        loose()
    else:
        draw()

def evaluate_paper():
    global computer_input
    if computer_input == "1":
        win()
    elif computer_input == "3":
        loose()
    else:
        draw()

def computer_choice(input):
    global computer_input
    computer_input = random.choice(list_of_integers)
    if computer_input == "1":
        computer_value = "Rock"
    elif computer_input == "2":
        computer_value = "paper"
    else:
        computer_value = "scissors"
    computer_result = Label(window, text= "the computer's choice was: " + computer_value , fg = "blue", bg = "green")
    computer_result.grid(column=3, row=3)
    if input == "rock":
        evaluate_rock()
    elif input == "scissors":
        evaluate_scissors()
    else:
        evaluate_paper()
    return computer_input

rock = Button(window, text="Rock", command= lambda: computer_choice("rock"), fg="green", bg="blue")
scissors = Button(window, text="Scissors", command = lambda: computer_choice("scissors"), fg = "black", bg = "blue")
paper = Button(window, text="paper", command = lambda: computer_choice("paper"), fg = "green", bg = "blue")

player_1 = Label(window, text = "Player 1", fg = "blue", bg = "red")
player_2 = Label(window, text= "Player 2", fg= "blue", bg= "red")

def evaluate():
    if player1input == player2input:
        result.configure(text= "Draw")
    elif player1input == "rock" and player2input == "scissors":
        result.configure(text= "Player 1 wins")
    elif player1input == "rock" and player2input == "paper":
        result.configure(text= "player 2 wins")
    elif player2input == "rock" and player1input == "scissors":
        result.configure(text= "Player 2 wins")
    elif player2input == "rock" and player1input == "paper":
        result.configure(text= "Player 1 wins")
    elif player1input == "paper" and player2input == "scissors":
        result.configure(text= "player 2 wins")
    elif player2input == "paper" and player1input == "scissors":
        result.configure(text= "Player 1 wins")
    reset1.grid(column= 3, row= 5)

def player_2_input(p2i):
    global player2input 
    player2input = p2i
    rock.destroy
    paper.destroy
    scissors.destroy
    player_2.destroy
    evaluate()
    return player2input

def player2():
    player_1.destroy
    player_2.grid(column= 3, row= 2)
    rock.configure(command = lambda: player_2_input("rock"))
    paper.configure(command= lambda: player_2_input("paper"))
    scissors.configure(command= lambda: player_2_input("scissors"))

def player_1_input(p1i):
    global player1input
    player1input = p1i
    player2()
    return player1input

def win():
    result.configure(text= "You Win")
    reset1.grid(column= 3, row= 5)

def loose():
    result.configure(text= "You loose")
    reset1.grid(column= 3, row= 5)

def draw():
    result.configure(text= "Draw")
    reset1.grid(column= 3, row= 5)

def place_buttons():
    result.grid(column=3, row=1)
    if player_number == 1:
        rock.grid(column=2, row=2)
        scissors.grid(column = 4, row=2)
        paper.grid(column = 3, row=2)
    elif player_number == 2:
        player_1.grid(column= 3, row= 2)
        rock.configure(command = lambda: player_1_input("rock"))
        paper.configure(command= lambda: player_1_input("paper"))
        scissors.configure(command= lambda: player_1_input("scissors"))
        rock.grid(column=2, row=3)
        scissors.grid(column = 4, row=3)
        paper.grid(column = 3, row=3)

one_player = Button(window, text = "One Player", command = lambda: [oneplayer(), place_buttons()])
two_players = Button(window, text= "Two players", command = lambda: [twoplayers(), place_buttons()])

def oneplayer():
    title.configure(text = "One player")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = 1
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()

def twoplayers():
    title.configure(text = "Two players")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = 2
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()

def add_fillers():
    global filler
    filler = Label(window, text = "                                                                   ")
    filler.grid(column=1, row=0)
    global filler2
    filler2 = Label(window, text = "                                                                   ")
    filler2.grid(column=0, row=0)
    global filler3
    filler3 = Label(window, text = "                                       ")
    filler3.grid(column=2, row=0)

def choose_player_number():
    one_player.grid(column= 2, row=1)
    two_players.grid(column= 4, row=1)

def run():  
    add_fillers()
    choose_player_number()

run()

window.mainloop()

I didn't find any solutions online since they were all case specific.
If someone has a solution i would love to know how to finally complete the code.

Your problem is causing on line 26, run(). Comment out #run()

that doesn't solve the problem, as the widgets aren't destroyed. it also doesn't restart the program which is what i want to achieve with the reset button

Here you find a solution, but it’s not the best in my opinion https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655930/12621346. Replace this two lines instead your run().

def reset():
filler.destroy
filler2.destroy
filler3.destroy
title.destroy
result.destroy
rock.after(3, rock.destroy)
paper.after(3, paper.destroy)
scissors.after(3, scissors.destroy)
computer_result.after(3, computer_result.destroy)
result.after(3, result.destroy)
reset1.after(3, reset1.destroy)
run()

def oneplayer():
title.configure(text = "One player")
title.grid(column=3, row=0)
global player_number
player_number = 1
one_player.grid_forget()
two_players.grid_forget()
rock.grid_forget()
paper.grid_forget()
scissors.grid_forget()
reset1.grid_forget()
computer_result.grid_forget()
result.grid_forget()


Same as twoplayer() too.

After that, still got  an error _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2" Try it yourself

computer_result = Label(window, fg = "blue", bg = "green")  must be outside of  function. And computer_result.configure(text= "the computer's choice was: " + computer_value) inside computer_choice() function.

Here is screenshot  

You destroy the two buttons one_player and two_players inside oneplayer() and twoplayers(), so when choose_player_numbers() is executed again by clicking reset1 button, exception will be raised.
Change the lines:
one_player.destroy()
two_players.estroy()

inside oneplayer() and twoplayers() to:
one_player.grid_forget()
two_players.grid_forget()

Note that even fixing this issue, your code still have other issues.

do you know why the other widgets aren't  being destroyed? Thanks for the help, i appreciate it!

@neo Because xxxx.destroy does not execute the destroy function on xxxx widget.  You need to call xxxx.destroy() instead.

Your import:
import tkinter as tk

Therefore your Buttons, Labels, and other widgets are named e.g. tk.Label(….):
reset1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Reset", command= reset, fg="blue", bg = "yellow")

I recommend you to read the  doc

Same error as OP got.

I don't understand what i am supposed to change.

Can you try the rename your window path name from the tkinter library 'init.py' file.
I think it will help to you or you can use the '_' behind of your path name words.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
