# Restart a program in Tkinter using a button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, python-requests

I'm new to Python and are trying to do a small program in which the GUI-window is supposed to re-open while clicking the button.

I read online that the line of code

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

is supposed to make your program restart, but all it does is exit the GUI-window and restart Shell totally clean.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os


def restart_program():
     os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)

window = Tk()
window.title("Test")
button = Button(window, text="RESTART", width=6, command=restart_program).grid(row=5, column=0)



window.mainloop()
```

This is the relevant part of my code atm (I didn't include all the code - some more widgets are adding to the existing, but it's not relevant to the problem). *Is there any way to re-open the window called "Test", especially without having to put it in a function?* Would be very thankful for help! :)))

Comment: What's wrong with putting it in a function? Reusing code is exactly what functions are for.

Comment: Where are you calling the `mainloop` function? I added the line `window.mainloop()` to the bottom of your code given, and when I run it and click the button it restarts as it should.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course there is going to be a mainloop function in the end (changed it in the question now). In my case, I only get this:>>> 
=============================== RESTART: Shell =============================== 
>>> I would like for the original window, the "Test"-window with the button, to appear again! Thankful for help!

Comment: The reason I don't want to put it in a function is because I have lots of more code that runs in to trouble when I make a new function... (I'm adding GUI to a already complete program) and nevertheless, the code os.excel.... seems to distant Shell from all previous functions. It's almost like Shell is restarting clean with nothing else

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE (e.g. IDLE or Anaconda) or in the command line? It will probably work in command line.

Comment: There are a few post already about this exact problem. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731887/resetting-the-main-gui-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655618/restart-program-tkinter). Probably a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting the main GUI window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731887/resetting-the-main-gui-window)

Comment: I have tested your code using Sypder3 IDE and also the terminal on Ubuntu18 and your code works correctly. As @johmsp mentioned, this issue might be related to your IDE or development environment.